# Basic authentication with the GitHub Api using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, github, basic-authentication, github-api

I have been trying to do [basic authentication with the GitHub Api](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/) with PowerShell. The following do not work:

```
 > $cred = get-credential
 # type username and password at prompt

 > invoke-webrequest -uri https://api.github.com/user -credential $cred

 Invoke-WebRequest : {
     "message":"Requires authentication",
     "documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"
 }
```

How do we do basic authentication using PowerShell with the GitHub Api?

Answer (score 17):

Basic auth basically expects that you send the credentials in an `Authorization` header in the following form:

```
'Basic [base64("username:password")]'
```

In PowerShell that would translate to something like:

```
function Get-BasicAuthCreds {
    param([string]$Username,[string]$Password)
    $AuthString = "{0}:{1}" -f $Username,$Password
    $AuthBytes  = [System.Text.Encoding]::Ascii.GetBytes($AuthString)
    return [Convert]::ToBase64String($AuthBytes)
}
```

And now you can do:

```
$BasicCreds = Get-BasicAuthCreds -Username "Shaun" -Password "s3cr3t"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $GitHubUri -Headers @{"Authorization"="Basic $BasicCreds"}
```