# Download a file from Remote Server(https) using powershell with credentials

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-4.0, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to download a file from Linux server with Apache web server to Windows Server 2012 R2 using Windows PowerShell

Note: the URL is HTTPS

```
$source = "https://uri"
$destination = "C:\path\file.txt"
$username = "admin"
$password = "@dfkl!f"  | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
Invoke-WebRequest $source -OutFile $destination -Credential $cred
```

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Authorization Required
This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document     requested. Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at url Port 443
```

When I type the credentials through browser i m able to download but through powershell it show bad credentials

Comment: Try use System.Net.WebClient + System.Net.CredentialCache as shown here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282842/how-to-login-to-website-with-basic-authentication-using-powershell

Comment: I tried with above solution but dint work... it shows 401 unauthorized error

Comment: It's seems that you need to inspect network traffic with tools like Ethereal

Comment: It might expect [basic authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27970200/712649)

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen I m trying in powershell so i created a same function thats shown in above answer but still same error appears

Comment: @naga4ce, is the webserver member of a domain? any chance username should be something like domain\admin?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this against one of my Apache/Linux boxes on a SSL page that uses Basic auth, and it seemed to work... Your mileage might vary...

```
$source = "https://Uri"
$destination = "C:\Foo\Bar"
$username = 'mylogin'
$password = 'reallgoodpassword'

$auth = 'Basic ' + [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($username+':'+$password ))

Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{ "Accept" = "*/*"; "Authorization" = $auth } -Uri $source -Method Get
```

Answer (score 0):

try to create the passwordstring with

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "@dfkl!f" -AsPlainText -Force
```